# Google App Engine Cron Job

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have created a `cron.xml` file and a servlet which describes the job.
Now when i compile and login as an admin, local development dashboard doesn't show Cron Jobs link.

Comment: Could you please post your cron.xml?

Answer (score 8):

Local development server does not have the Cron Jobs link neither does it execute cron jobs. The actual appengine will show cron jobs and will execute them.

You can manually execute cron jobs on local server by visiting their urls. e.g.
http://localhost:8888/FindReservedBooksTask.

BTW the cron.xml file should be in the war/WEB-INF directory.

Comment: http://localhost:8888/FindReservedBooksTask does not seem to be working any more. Any workaround ?

Comment: When visiting the local cron URLs and having security-constraints enabled, use an incognito window and log in with the admin flag enabled to bypass security.

Answer (score 2):

The dev appserver doesn't automatically run your cron jobs. You can use your local desktop's cron or scheduled tasks interface to hit the URLs of your jobs with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or a similar tool.

Here is the link to the GAE [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Cron_Support_in_the_Development_Server) on this.

Also, make sure you disable all security constraints for your crons in the web.xml. If you don't have them -- you should [restrict cron to admin accounts](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_appengine_web_xml_Securing_URLs_for_cron).

Comment: Please explain the security advice, disable==don't, should==do.

Answer (score -2):

This [`website`](http://rominirani.com/2009/11/16/episode-9-using-the-cron-service-to-run-scheduled-tasks/) walks you through the way to use cron jobs inside of Google App Engine.

Also, The Google App Engine provides a service called the [Cron Service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html) that helps us do two fundamental things:

1. Allows your application to schedule these tasks.
2. Execute these tasks based on their schedule.

Comment: The linked website fails to answer the local development problem.  The standard Cron Service documentation is obviously understood and was already linked in the previous answer.  Therefore this answer is too superficial and adds nothing.